# bindlinglist is updated but datagridview is not

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

I have the following code that I use to update my datagridview:

```
public readonly BindingList<InventoryTransaction> InventoryTransactions = new BindingList<InventoryTransaction>() { RaiseListChangedEvents = true };
private bool _scanning;
private string _checkData;

public BarCodeForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  barCodeForm_InventoryTransactionBindingSource.DataSource = InventoryTransactions;

  panel1.Enabled = false;
  _scanning = true;
  timer_ScanTimer.Enabled = false;
  //InventoryTransactions.AddingNew += InventoryTransactions_AddingNew;
}


private void timer_ScanTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  panel1.Enabled = true;
  label_Message.Text = "Please press ENTER or click RESET to scan again.";
  timer_ScanTimer.Enabled = false;

  textBox_ModelNumber.Text = _checkData;
  textBox_Quantity.Text = "1";

  var qry = (from x in InventoryTransactions
    where x.ModelNumber == _checkData
    select x).FirstOrDefault();

  _checkData = string.Empty;

  if (qry == null)
  {
    textBox_Quantity.Focus();        
    return;
  }

  qry.Quantity += qry.Quantity;
  barCodeForm_InventoryTransactionBindingSource.EndEdit();

  panel1.Enabled = false;
  _scanning = true;
  timer_ScanTimer.Enabled = false;
  panel1.Text = "Scan now!";

  ResetForm();
}
```

The problem is that I have updated the quantity of the InventoryTransactions but my datagridview is not updating. Do I have to issue a command of some sort to force the update or to apply the changes?

Thanks!

Comment: I set the datasource to null then set it back to the bindinglist. That seemed to work. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce what you describe. My test shows that the grid will update as soon as the `BindingList` is updated without adding any code. I may be missing something but I do not see in the `timer_ScanTimer_Tick` event “where” the `BindingList` is being updated. It appears your query `qry` executes but the results do not appear to be used. Am I missing something?